# Minimum support apriori algorithm a thumb rule

Tags: algorithm, data-mining, apriori

Can I use the following rule of thumb as the first estimation for minimum support

```
*min support* = total number of transaction where I have N items / total number of transactions
```

where L is the max length of the rules I want to analyze.

Ex:

```
Transactions  ITEMS
1              A
1              B
3              C 
4              A
4              C
5              D 

min supp = 2/5 = 0,4%
```

Comment: The question does not make sense. There is no `L` in your equation.

Comment: 1-element transactions are pretty much useless, btw. You need a substantial amount of at least 4 element transactions for this approach to make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule of thumb is:

As little as you deem a non-random occurrence.

In some cases, 1 will be required. Sometimes 2.
But if you are analyzing say all of Amazon or all of Walmart, 1000 may be the minimum you need.

It really depends on:

- your data
- your use case
- how much computation you can afford